# In Java how to create a list of strings that I can iterate by name?

Tags: java, string, loops, enums

What is the best way to create a list of Strings such that I can:

(1) Iterate easily like:

```
 for (String p : Privilege.PRIVILEGES) {}
```

(2) Can reference by name like:

```
String p = Privilege.PRIVILEGES.READ_ACCESS  //string with value "READ_ACCESS"
```

Comment: An `Enum` could work for you?

Comment: I tried but it’s messy because you can’t get the string value unless you call .name() each time

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so easy to understand, but I think that below can help you.

> What is the best way to create a list of Strings

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("String1", "String2", "String3");
```

> (1) Iterate easily 
>   (2) Can reference by name

```
String value = list.stream().filter(elem -> "String2".equals(elem)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: But you cant name those elements. I want to be able to say List.FIRSTITEM and have it return a string

Comment: itens from enum?

Comment: If is a enum, you can do it:

`List<Privilege> somethingList = Arrays.asList(Privilege.values());`
and it
`Privilege enumElem = enumList.stream().filter(elem -> Privilege.P1.equals(elem)).findFirst().orElse(null);`
`enumElem.name()`

Pls validate null.